# compact headless energy meter

Tags: power-measurement

I'm looking for a way to monitor the power of several circuits at home: Washer, dryer, freezer etc.

I already have a modbus meter for the heatpump, but I don't have room for an extra meter on the DIN-bar, even if they are available in 1-unit with.

So I'm looking for an unit which have (multiple) input from current transformer and a modbus or other raspberry-compatible output. Wifi would be ok too.

The unit need to calculate the energy itself, I don't want to have to poll regularly for the watt and add it myself.

Suggestions?